# URL Mapping works on localhost but not on production server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have certain values that are `mapped` in `web.config` file for `URL Mapping`. When i browse for file it works on `localhost`. But, when i deploy this application on `IIS` on Production it wont work. shows Error: "`404: The resource cannot be found.`" dont know why?

Any idea?

**Web.config markup:**

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
      <add url="~/Pune" mappedUrl="~/City.aspx?ID=1"/>
</urlMappings>
```

**In .aspx file:**

```
<a href="Pune">Pune City</a>
```

After searching i have got some clue that it must be:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
          <add url="~/Pune" mappedUrl="http://mycustomdomain.com/City.aspx?ID=1"/>
</urlMappings>
```

But, unfortunately this too wont work..!

Anything else..do we need to do settings in `IIS` or `web.config` file?

Answer (score 1):

To do this just follow steps:

**For IIS 7:**
open IIS manager , double click on the website , double click Handler Mappings , right click on the specific handler , click Request Restrictions and uncheck the checkbox Invoke handler only if request is mapped to.

Answer (score 1):

See this:
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1523272.aspx?urlmappings+stopped+when+moved+to+ii7](http://forums.asp.net/t/1523272.aspx?urlmappings%20stopped%20when%20moved%20to%20ii7)

Url mappings should not be supported in IIS 7 - you should use [Url Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)